# How to customize individual numbers on an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I'm trying to overlay these two plots, and so far I think I might have it but  the first number on the top y-axis and last number on the bottom y-axis are overlapping each other.  Is there a way to individually edit each number on the y-axis so I can delete one of the two, as well make each one different from the other?

[image]

This plot ^^ is from the same code below but without the line `plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in plot.axes[:-1]], visible=False)`

```
##Plotting
plt.close('all')
pressure_plot, dyn = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
dyn[0].plot(s,p1_dyn,
         s, p2_dyn)
dyn[1].plot(s,A)
plot.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in plot.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

I was thinking it might be possible to use this last line here ^^ to delete one, because if you change it to yticklabels() it will remove a y axis (like seen below).  But I'm not sure how to get it to individually delete one. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the top y value of the axis by doing:

```
yticks = plt.gca().get_yticks().tolist() # get list of ticks
yticks[-1] = ''                          # set last tick to empty string
ax.set_yticklabels(yticks)
```

Comment: Submitted an edit for it, that corrected it for my specific code. Just had to fix a few things but overall that worked perfectly, thanks!